# Como identificar uma data específica em vba?

Tags: data, excel-vba

Tenho uma base com datas de diversos meses e anos, e uma tela inicial onde atualizo a data de submissão e insiro as informações.

Fiz um código que vai identificar o mês e ano da tela inicial, vai identificar o mês e ano na base e preencher as informações lá.
Mas acho que o código não está identificando a data.
Segue o código.

```
ub Abastecer_base_total()

Set inicio2 = Application.Sheets("2")
Set inicio3 = Application.Sheets("3")
Set inicio4 = Application.Sheets("4")
Set inicio5 = Application.Sheets("5")
Set inicio6 = Application.Sheets("6")
Set inicioDEPARA = Application.Sheets("DE PARA")
Set inicioBASETOTAL = Application.Sheets("Base total")

a = Month(inicio2.Cells(3, 4).Value)
b = Year(inicio2.Cells(3, 4).Value)

l = 3

Do Until inicioBASETOTAL.Cells(3, l).Value = "01 / a / b"

l = l + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: tem certeza que os valores das variáveis `a` e `b` são interpoladas corretamente? Não conheço o suficiente de VBA, mas parece que esse é o problema

Comment: Olá Bruno. Muito obrigada pela sua resposta e disponibilidade em me ajudar! O que vc quer dizer com interpoladas corretamente? A variável a é o mês e b é o ano... entao quando eu faço "01/a/b" ele deveria ver ou ler 01/7/2017... no caso a data que eu estava tentando ler...

Comment: Interpolação  é exatamente a substituição das variaveis dentro da string. Não tenho certeza de como isso funciona no VBA, mas tenho a impressão que `"01 / a / b"` não vai fuincioar pois a comparação vai ser com os valores literais `a` e `b`. tente algo como: `"01 / " & a & " / " & b`, para concatenar os valores antes de comparar.

Comment: Segundo essa resposta no SO, não existe interpolação de variáveis e o melhor caminho é concatenação dos valores mesmo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221349/vba-string-interpolation-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Bruno Coimbra falou da interpolação, ela não é possível.
Porém é possível trabalhar com a data em formato `Long` e depois convertê-la para `Date` novamente.

As funções utilizadas são as de [conversão de Tipo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/PT-BR/library/office/gg278896.aspx): `CLng()` e `CDate()`

Por exemplo você pode extrair o mês e ano:

```
mesAno= (Right(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D3"), 7)) ' mesAno = 08-2017
```

E extrair o número de dias daquele mês:

```
 intDaysInMonth = day(DateSerial(Year(mesAno), Month(mesAno) + 1, 0))
```

Criando um loop com o número de dias daquele mês:

```
For i = 0 To intDaysInMonth - 1
End For
```

Um exemplo para procurar um mês e ano específico:

```
Dim monthYear As Date
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, cellFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row


    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 4), ws.Cells(lastrow, 4))
    mesAno= (Right(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D3"), 7)) ' mesAno = 08-2017
    intDaysInMonth = day(DateSerial(Year(mesAno), Month(mesAno) + 1, 0))

  For i = 0 To intDaysInMonth - 1
        LookingFor = CLng(mesAno) + i
        LookingForString = CStr(CDate(LookingFor))
        With rng
            Set cellFound = .Find(what:=LookingForString, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
                    Do
                        Debug.Print cellFound.Address
                        Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
                    Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
                 End If
        End With
    Next i
```

Você primeiro transforma para Long e obtém um número inteiro que corresponde a cada Data desde 01/01/1900 e soma com o Loop de cada dia que aquele mês contém:

```
LookingFor = CLng(mesAno) + i
```

Após isso você transforma para `Date` com `CDate` e depois para `String` com `CStr`

```
LookingForString = CStr(CDate(LookingFor))
```

Está extenso e nível acima de básico, mas para trabalhar com Datas você pode trabalhar com elas no Tipo Data ou convertê-las para Long e trabalhar. Por exemplo, você tentou utilizar um loop, portanto, trabalhar no formato `Long` deve facilitar isso.